# How do I access and modify properties of other objects while in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uislider

I'm using XCode and am very new to Objective-C programming.

I've created a program with a UISlider. How can I modify the properties of that slider (like its value, or currentThumbImage) with code placed inside of viewDidLoad?

In essence, my greater question is: how do I access properties of other objects with code in a DIFFERENT method?

I apologize if my phrasing of the question is confusing. Please let me know if there's anything I can specify in more detail.

edit: I have an UISlider in my single view application.

I would like to change the slider's thumb image by using code in the viewDidLoad method.
This is the code I put in the viewDidLoad method.

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
[slider setThumbImage:@"image.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But it does not seem to change the image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear and confusing. You will need to rephrase your question with some more detail.

Comment: Would you add your code to understand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to declare an IBOutlet for your slider, instead of an IBAction.

To do so, control-drag your slider between `@interface YourViewController` and `@end`, instead of between `@implementation YourViewController` and `@end`

It will look like

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mySlider setThumbImage:@"image.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

Comment: It worked! So if I ever need to be able to modify a UI element's properties, I have to connect it as both an outlet AND an action?

Comment: @bibekg You need to connect IBOutlet and IBAction whenever you are using elements on XIB's. But when you are using them programmatically than you don't need to connect them as than they will not be visible in the XIB.

Comment: @bibekg You can just connect them both, they are not exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Declare [UISlider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Object in the .h file so that it's global and you can access it in your .m file after that you need to initialize the object of `UISlider` with a corresponding method to its event changes and later in that method you can access all the properties you need given is the code for the same.

Please note you can initialize the object in view did load or view will appear method

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

slider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame of your choice)];
slider.maximumValue = 100; // max value you want for slider
slider.minimumValue = 1;   // min value you want for slider

// associating a method which will respond to the slider value change event
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// adding slider control as subview to current view
[self.view addSubview:slider];

}
```

and inside the sliderValueChange method you can access any property of the slider control you like

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged
{
  someLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",slider.value];
}
```

Where `someLabel` is the object of [UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) class, If you are looking around for a tutorial with XIB files then [here is the link to that](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-uislider-basics-for-apple-ios/) which might be of some use.

Comment: My UISlider is in my viewController.h file as an IBAction connected from the storyboard. Is that what you mean by declare it in the header file?

Comment: ya @bibekg do let me know if the answer helped you.

Comment: You were right, I did need to declare it. But apparently not as an IBAction. Once I added a connection as an Outlet, I was able to access the slider's properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    slider.maximumValue = 100.0;
    slider.minimumValue = 1.0;
    slider.thumbTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
   [self.view addSubview:slider];
}
```

Comment: If u created your slider in storyboard means have a outlet for that slider by using that u can access properties of slider.